# Angular app generating 404 on refresh deployed on weblogic url rewriting is enabled

Tags: angular, weblogic

I have deployed my app on weblogic server. I have redirected 404 error on index.html, but whenever I try to hit direct URL or refresh the page its showing me 404 error first time in networks.

It's an Angular 4 app.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure you are setting the useHash variable to true:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...

const routes: Routes = [//routes in here];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then what worked for me was trying a different base href to see which one works on weblogic.  If refresh works on webpack dev server, then you might need a different base href for weblogic.   You can change the baseref with webpack using something like https://github.com/dzonatan/base-href-webpack-plugin.

```
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('base-href-webpack-plugin');

// Add to plugins
plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), // Required dependency
   new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/' })
]
```